# How to extract all paragraphs that start with a specific word?

Tags: python, string, text, paragraph

I'm practicing working with strings, and I would like some help:
I have a text as a string that I extracted doing web scraping. It's a play where several characters speak. **I want to grab only the lines of a specific character**. Every character speaks in a new paragraph. Let's say this is the string:

```
Character 1: aaaaaaaaaaa.
Character 2: bbbbbbb.
Character 3: ccc.
Character 1: ddddddd.
Character 3: eeee.
```

I only want to grab what Character 1. The string character1 should be:

```
aaaaaaaaaaa.ddddddd.
```

As a general example of what I tried:

```
def select_lines(text, paragraph_ending, keyword):
    for i in text:
        if text.startswith(keyword):
            text.split(paragraph_ending)

character1 = select_lines(voices, '\n', 'Character 1: ')
print(character1)
```

Comment: so, `voices` is a string? or is a list of strings? It's not clear what your input is. please show us how you create the `voices` variable

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki The op did specify in the question that it is a string and also you can't perform split function on lists

Answer (score 1):

It first splits the string into a list of paragraphs and checks if each paragraph starts with the keyword. If it does then it removes the keyword from it and adds it to a variable and after that it returns the result variable.

```
data = 'Character 1: aaaaaaaaaaa.\nCharacter 2: bbbbbbb.\nCharacter 3: ccc.\nCharacter 1: ddddddd.\nCharacter 3: eeee.'

def select_lines(text, paragraph_ending, keyword):
    paras = text.split(paragraph_ending)
    result = ''
    for para in paras:
        if ( para.startswith( keyword ) ):
            x = para.replace(keyword, '')
            result += x

    return result

character1 = select_lines(data, '\n', 'Character 1: ')
print(character1)
```

Comment: This is great. For OP, you could potentially extend this by passing in a list of character keys and returning multiple strings with some modification of the search.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. It seems I still have a lot to learn.